# Regex in SQL Server Replace function

Tags: sql-server, string-matching

I have a variable with random text, let's say

```
DECLARE @sNumberFormat NVARCHAR(200) = 'rand{text.here,{999}also-Random9He8re'
```

I want to replace each `9` in `{999}` by `[0-9]`. So in this example I would like to get

```
'rand{text.here,[0-9][0-9][0-9]also-Random9He8re'
```

Problem is I never know how many `9` will be placed in brackets, so there can be `{99}` `{9999}` ..and go on. I also need to validate if there is any invalid character (not `9`) then nothing should be replaced.

I have tried some combinations of `REPLACE` and `PATINDEX` functions, but I could not achieve that.

Comment: SQL Server has no Regex support, and it's pattern matching abilities is rudimentary at best.

Answer (score 0):

Sans robust regex support, SQL Server's native functions do not give much help here.  One approach, a bit hackish, would be to separate the input string into three components:

```
rand{text.here,
{999}
also-Random9He8re
```

Next, replace the `9` in the middle target substring with `@`, or some other character which you don't expect to appear anywhere else in your input string:

```
rand{text.here,
{@@@}
also-Random9He8re
```

Finally, replace the `@` in the middle substring with `[0-9]` and then concatenate together to get the final result:

```sql
DECLARE @val NVARCHAR(200) = 'rand{text.here,{999}also-Random9He8re'

SELECT REPLACE(
           SUBSTRING(@val, 1, CHARINDEX('{9', @val) - 1) +
           REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@val,
                            CHARINDEX('{9', @val) + 1,
                            CHARINDEX('9}', @val) - CHARINDEX('{9', @val)), '9', '@') +
           SUBSTRING(@val, CHARINDEX('9}', @val) + 2, LEN(@val) - CHARINDEX('9}', @val)),
           '@', '[0-9]');
```

Answer (score 0):

So the lazy dev in me suggests this:

```sql
SELECT Replace(
         Replace(
           Replace(
             Replace(@input, '{9999}', '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
           , '{999}', '[0-9][0-9][0-9]')
         , '{99}', '[0-9][0-9]')
       , '{9}', '[0-9]') AS result
;
```

You can keep extending as long as you like to perform your (one off?) replacements.

Quick. Simple. Extensible. **Hacky**.

Sometimes lazy is *good enough*.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with CTE series. It works with an arbitrary number of "9" values in square brackets.

```
Declare @str varchar(max) = 'rand{text.here,{999}also-Random9He8re';

With A As 
(Select 1 As Pos
Union All 
Select Pos+1 As Pos From A Where Pos < LEN(@str)
),
B As (
Select STRING_AGG(Case When Chr Like '[{9}]' Then Chr Else ' ' End, '') As Chr 
From A Cross Apply (Select SUBSTRING(@str,A.Pos,1 )) As T(chr)
),
C As (
Select [value] As pattern, 
       REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([value], '9', '[0-9]'),'{',''),'}','') As replacement, 
       ROW_NUMBER() Over (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) As Num, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) As Cnt
From B Cross Apply STRING_SPLIT(Chr,' ')
Where [value] Like '{%}' And [value] Like '%9%'
),
D As (
Select @str As Result, 1 As Num
Union All 
select REPLACE(Result, C.pattern, C.replacement) As Res , D.Num+1 As Num
From D Inner Join C On (D.Num=C.Num)
Where D.Num<=C.Cnt)
Select Top 1 Result
From D
Order by Num Desc
```

- A - Getting a list of character positions in text
- B - Getting text with spaces instead of characters other than
  '9','{','}'
- C- Getting patterns and corresponding replacement values
- D - Getting the result using REPLACEMENT function